# DSN-less ODBC Connection to iSeries

Tags: php, odbc, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

I'm running PHP 5.2.4 with ibm_db2 v1.8.0 on Ubuntu 8.04.1 Server. I am trying to hit an IBM iSeries running OS/400 v5R3 but I'm not sure at all how to actually connect without a DSN. I've looked at http://www.connectionstrings.com/ but none of the DB2 or AS/400 connection strings seem to work. All I end up with is:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1013N The database alias name or database name "" could not be found. SQLSTATE=42705 SQLCODE=-1013
```

Here is my current DSN string:

```
DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=192.168.0.20;Uid=user;Pwd=password
```

I've also tried the 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER' but get the same error as the string above.

Comment: Anyone reading this might also be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184302/connecting-to-an-ibm-as-400-db2-database/19184608#19184608).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to use ODBC as there wasn't an easy way to access DBU from PHP without having to set up DB2-C and pipe everything through there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use within the .NET environment:

```
Provider=IBMDA400.DataSource.1;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=SERVERNAME
```

You might be missing the "Initial Catalog".