# Connecting to an IBM AS/400 DB2 Database

Tags: ubuntu, db2, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to a client's IBM AS/400 DB2 Database from an Ubuntu Server using PHP's **ODBC Driver**. I have the **unixODBC** installed as well. My **odbcinst.ini** looks like this:

```
[IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER]
Description = ODBC 5.1 Driver for Database
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
FileUsage = 1
```

And my **odbc.ini** looks like this:

```
[IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER]
Driver = IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER
Description = ODBC 5.1 Driver DSN
```

Now, my code to connect is:

```
$server = '12.345.678.90' //IP
$port = '446' //PORT
$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';

$connect = odbc_connect("DRIVER = {IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};System=$server:$port;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password;", $username, $password);

if(!$connect)
    echo 'Cannot Connect!';
else
    echo 'Connected!';
```

The error I get is this:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL Error: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES), SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect
```

I tried using the PDO ODBC Driver also. This is the error I get:

```
$connect = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};HOSTNAME=$server;PORT=$port;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password");

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 1045 [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /var/www/test_file.php Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test_file.php: PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={IB...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/test_file.php
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Do I need to use some other driver, because the username and password are correct, I saw the client log in to the database using the username and password I have. I thought the username and password were wrong because it says **Access Denied for user**. It doesn't seem to be the case. There might be something else that's wrong.

Thank you for your help. I hope I made the problem very clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your odbcinst.ini file is saying to use the MySQL ODBC driver:

```
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
```

but you need to use the *iSeries Access ODBC* driver.  The reason you're getting an `Access Denied for User` message is because you're trying to connect to your MySQL database with credentials for the IBM i.

Here are step by step instructions for how to connect to DB2 for i (on the IBM i) on Ubuntu:

Download the free `iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm` file from IBM (you'll have to create a free account to get it - and I'm sure there is a more recent version than 6.1.0-1.2)

Convert the RPM file to something Ubuntu understands: `sudo alien iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm`

Install the resulting .deb: `sudo dpkg -i iseriesaccess_6.1.0-2.2_i386.deb`

Copy the installed iSeries libraries to where Ubuntu expects them: `sudo cp /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/* /usr/lib`

Edit the **/etc/odbc.ini** file to contain:

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = IP_ADDRESS
UserID                  = USERNAME
Password                = PASSWORD
Naming                  = 1
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
```

Edit the **/etc/odbcinst.ini** file to contain:

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

And then to create the connection with PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$server;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had installed **iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0x86_64.rpm** because I couldn't install the **i386**. Let me try with the one that you provided. But I cannot install for the **i386** architechture. Thanks. Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only difference between the **odbcinst.ini** that you provided and mine is:  

    **Driver = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so**  
    **Setup = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodc.so**

Everything else was the same.

I tried to connect using PDO, but the error message I got was that the **libcwbodbc.so** was not found. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @flyingDuck - You'll need to make sure your `odbcinst.ini` file has `Driver = xxx` and `Setup = xxx` lines that point to where ever your **libcwbodbc.so** is located.

Comment: Thanks again! I couldn't log in to the IBM website to download version 6.1, but I had downloaded the 7.1 yesterday, so I used that. I used your **ini** files and copied files in the `**/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64**` to `**/usr/lib**`. So now my **odbcinst.ini** file has `Driver = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so` and also the same for **Setup (libcwbodbcs.so)**. Now I get this error ` 10061 [unixODBC][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver] Communication link failure. comm rc = 10061 - CWBC01049 - The IBM i server application is not started, or the connection was blocked by a firewall'` Thanks

Comment: Thank You very much! I got it to connect. I was using the wrong IP Address. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: You might consider changing the [Naming setting](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikconnstrkeywordsservprop.htm) to 1.  IBM i developers generally consider it best practice to use the library list (similar to a path).  [System vs SQL Naming -part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-sqlnaming/) & [part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-system_sql2/index.html)

Comment: If your server is v6.1 or v7.1, and up to date (TR 5+ ?) then "system naming" allows the schema.table notation used in "sql naming".

Comment: (Side note: You may be surprised to learn that you AS/400 probably isn't actually an AS/400. IBM shipped the last one in 2000.  The product line was re-branded as iSeries, but later merged with pSeries, and is currently known as Power Systems, running IBM i.)

Comment: I'm facing this issue right now, but I didn't found the download of `iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0x86_64.rpm`. Any tips?

Comment: @icy2k - this page looks like a good place to start:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzatv/rzatvinstall.htm

Comment: @BennyHill yes, in that page there is a point with "Download the Linux Application Package archive file." But where is it? Really I can't found out.

Comment: @icy2k - it appears you need to go here (http://www-304.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess/index.wss) and login in order to get to the software. Beyond that, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

I had to get IBM/DB2 access working with ODBC / PHP on a Ubuntu box recently.
You can probably adapt this for most other distros:
Here's how I got it working:

[1] Download one of the following, depending on your required DB2 version and architecture

```
iSeriesAccess-5.4.0-1.6.i386.rpm
iSeriesAccess-5.4.0-1.6.ppc.rpm  
iSeriesAccess-5.4.0-1.6.ppc64.rpm
iSeriesAccess-5.4.0-1.6.x86_64.rpm
iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.i386.rpm
iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.ppc.rpm   
iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.ppc64.rpm
iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

You can get this from the IBM website, or from here:

http://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/public.dhe.ibm.com/as400
(According to feedback, this opens NSFW popups. It's not my site, sorry about that - if you have concerns, go with the IBM website).

Then install IBM as400 client Access using something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install alien libmotif3
cd /path/to/iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.i386.rpm
sudo alien -dckv iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.i386.rpm
sudo dpkg -i iseriesaccess_6.1.0-1.0_i386.deb
```

[2] Install Java (if needed)

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

[3] Install UNIXODBC

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-bin
```

[4] Install PHP ODBC

```
sudo apt-get install php5-odbc
```

[5] Ldconfig
Create a file  `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/iSeriesAccess.conf` with this line:

```
/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/
```

Then run the following:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

[6] Register driver

```
sudo odbcinst -i -d -f /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/unixodbcregistration
```

[7] Test it with some PHP code

```
<?php
$user = 'SomeUser';
$pass = 'SomePass';
$Conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};DATABASE=DBNAME;SYSTEM=127.0.0.1;HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1;PORT=446;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $user, $pass);
if($Conn === false){
    die('failed to connect');
}
$sql = "select * from database.table fetch first 10 rows only";

$result=odbc_exec($Conn,$sql);

echo '<pre>';

while(odbc_fetch_array(($result)){
         print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: the link to mmnt.com opens NSFW popups.

Answer (score 0):

The web link in Silas' (excellent) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565590/15058786) is a listing of ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/as400 , which you can access directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mohammadmobasher  cannot comment yet, so posted this info as an answer