# Python cannot execute AS400 DB2 query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, ibm-midrange

I cannot connect to AS400 version of DB2 via SQLAlchemy (both ibm_db, ibm_db_sa libraries stall when executing queries).  The link below gives a solution via ODBC and pyodbc but I only have access to an ubuntu server and not windows for this task.  Any suggestions on how to make python work with AS400 DB2?

[Connecting to IBM AS400 server for database operations hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461388/connecting-to-ibm-as400-server-for-database-operations-hangs/35494302#35494302)

Comment: Problem isn't clear. Are you restricted from ODBC for some reason? Do you need to know about obtaining the driver for Linux?

Comment: Here is an [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184302/connecting-to-an-ibm-as-400-db2-database/19184608#19184608) of mine that talks about setting up an Ubuntu server to connect to an IBM i server via ODBC. [This old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925825/having-troubles-with-unixodbc-freetds-and-pyodbc/17113723#17113723) may also be helpful.